# Birthday paradox - Strictly more birthdays

Tags: probability

The question is,

> Suppose there are k students in a class and every student is equally
>   likely to be born in any of the twelve months of the year. 
>   If k = 12, what is the probability strictly more students have birthdays in the first
>   6 months of the year than the second 6 months of the year.

I don't even know how to begin with this question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the birthday paradox

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the number of student having birthday in the first $6$ months.

then $X$ follows distribution $Bin(12, \frac12)$.

You just have to compute $P(X>6)$.

Note that $$P(X>6)+P(X<6)+P(X=6)=1$$

By symmetry, $P(X>6)=P(X<6)$.

$$P(X>6)=\frac12 \left(1-P(X=6) \right)$$

Also, $P(X=6)= \binom{12}{6}\frac1{2^{12}}$